# SQL Integration Services: XMLA or SSIS to Load CSV

Tags: sql, ssis, ddl, xmla

Is it better to use XMLA or SSIS to load/import CSV data into a database? My sys admin recommends using XMLA + DDL to load the data instead of traditional SSIS.

To me it sounds like SSIS is the preferred way.

Any suggestions will help greatly.

Comment: He means http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187178(v=sql.90).aspx ?

Comment: I am not sure what you were trying to point out. I "kind of" having an understanding of XMLA and SSIS...

Comment: See santi's respose, that's what i am pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMLA has nothing to do with loading a CSV file. If you just need to load CSV data into a relational database, use SSIS. If you need to consume multidimensional data, or change the schema of an Analysis Services database, use XMLA.